PK pass auto update
Need some help if anyone can help.
Recently i made a pkpass of a gym membership so i can share with work colleagues. At the moment the gym only allows one phone per pass so decided to create pkpass so i am able to share with colleagues at work. I no longer am in touch with these colleagues yet they still use this pkpass i sent them without my permission. Is it possible to stop autoupdates to all passes even though they have now added the pkpass into their iphones? Thanks in advance.
Nothing so far. Awaiting community reply

This site is for development questions only. Apple user questions please post on https://apple.stackexchange.com
